# How to do some process on another thread and add data to sqflit and appsharedprefs with flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, process, background

I'm trying to start a background process on splash screen, which would get data from server do some process and save it to database and set some sharedprefs value too while the app runs the normal way it's going to.
I tried using compute and Isolate.spawn but because of using appsharedprefs and trying to access database there are some problems and crashes because database and appsharedprefs are on main channel while isolate uses it's own memory and thread.
Here is an example of exception while trying to init my sharedprefs:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance value is invalid until BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed.
```

the simple way to put what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
        splashscreen{
    compute(backgroundprocess.getdata,null);
    }
    class backgroundprocess{
      static getdata(){
        apsharedprefs prefs = apsharedprefs();
        prefs.init;
        String date = prefs.get('date');
        var dataToInsertToDb = getdatafordate(date);
        var db = mydatabase.db;
        db.insert(dataToInsertToDb);
}}
```